# Rolling 3 Current Year and Same Period Previous year total

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

Looking for a solution to sum a measure for the rolling 3 month period through the last date of data available (typically each end of month) for the current year and the same period in the prior year.

I've solved the current year total with this formula

```
SUMX(DATESINPERIOD(Ad_Data_for_Excel[AD START],
LASTDATE(Ad_Data_for_Excel[AD START]),-3,MONTH),
[Ad Count])
```

---

I have a data sheet with a dynamic ending date that is typically through the end of the prior month (e.g. September 30th data completed in October) and I'm trying to solve for a sum of the items for the latest Rolling 3 month period to be mirrored by the same Rolling 3 month period for the prior year (to make a comparison of the 3 month periods simple).  It's just a simple sum and I have this year solved but haven't been able to find a solution for the same period prior year.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could be `SUMX(DATESINPERIOD(Ad_Data_for_Excel[AD START],
LASTDATE(Ad_Data_for_Excel[AD START])-365,-3,MONTH),
[Ad Count])`?

Comment: This appears to capture it!  I hadn't used something like the -365,-3, MONTH before and it may help me in other areas.  thank you